# How to active functionality of time in every tile and continue timer after browser is closed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

I want to display timer using html multiple div.I am able to load timer for first div,but I want my timer `on` only that div I clicked.For the first div,its working fine,but other div is not able to start timer.Timer also stop when browser is refreshed or closed.I want to continue timer when browser is refreshed or closed by other's.I am giving my code below :

```
(function($){
        var row =document.getElementById('row').value;
        //alert("I am testing"+row);
        $.extend({
            APP : {                
                formatTimer : function(a) {
                    if (a < 10) {
                        a = '0' + a;
                    }                              
                    return a;
                }, 

                startTimer : function(dir) {
                    var a;
                    // save type
                    $.APP.dir = dir;
                    // get current date
                    $.APP.d1 = new Date();
                    switch($.APP.state) {
                        case 'pause' :
                            // resume timer
                            // get current timestamp (for calculations) and
                            // substract time difference between pause and now
                            $.APP.t1 = $.APP.d1.getTime() - $.APP.td;                            
                        break;
                        default :
                            // get current timestamp (for calculations)
                            $.APP.t1 = $.APP.d1.getTime(); 
                            // if countdown add ms based on seconds in textfield
                            if ($.APP.dir === 'cd') {
                                $.APP.t1 += parseInt($('#cd_seconds').val())*1000;
                            }    
                        break;
                    }                                   
                    // reset state
                    $.APP.state = 'alive';   
                    $('#' + $.APP.dir + '_status').html('Running');
                    // start loop
                    $.APP.loopTimer();
                },

                pauseTimer : function() 
                {
                    // save timestamp of pause
                    $.APP.dp = new Date();
                    $.APP.tp = $.APP.dp.getTime();
                    // save elapsed time (until pause)
                    $.APP.td = $.APP.tp - $.APP.t1;
                    // change button value
                    $('#' + $.APP.dir + '_start').val('Resume');
                    // set state
                    $.APP.state = 'pause';
                    $('#' + $.APP.dir + '_status').html('Paused');
                },

                stopTimer : function() {
                    // change button value
                    $('#' + $.APP.dir + '_start').val('Restart');                    
                    // set state
                    $.APP.state = 'stop';
                    $('#' + $.APP.dir + '_status').html('Stopped');
                },

                resetTimer : function() 
                {
                  // reset display
                  $('#' + $.APP.dir + '_ms,#' + $.APP.dir + '_s,#' + $.APP.dir + '_m,#' + $.APP.dir + '_h').html('00');                 
                  // change button value
                  $('#' + $.APP.dir + '_start').val('Start');                    
                  // set state
                  $.APP.state = 'reset';  
                  $('#' + $.APP.dir + '_status').html('Reset & Idle again');

                },
                endTimer : function(callback) 
                {
                  // change button value
                  $('#' + $.APP.dir + '_start').val('Restart');
                  // set state
                  $.APP.state = 'end';
                  // invoke callback
                  if (typeof callback === 'function') 
                  {
                    callback();
                  }    
                },    

                    loopTimer : function() {
                    var td;
                    var d2,t2;
                    var ms = 0;
                    var s  = 0;
                    var m  = 0;
                    var h  = 0;
                    if ($.APP.state === 'alive') {
                        // get current date and convert it into 
                        // timestamp for calculations
                        d2 = new Date();
                        t2 = d2.getTime();   
                        // calculate time difference between
                        // initial and current timestamp
                        if ($.APP.dir === 'sw') {
                            td = t2 - $.APP.t1;
                        // reversed if countdown
                        } else {
                            td = $.APP.t1 - t2;
                            if (td <= 0) {
                                //if time difference is 0 end countdown
                                $.APP.endTimer(function(){
                                    $.APP.resetTimer();
                                    $('#' + $.APP.dir + '_status').html('Ended & Reset');
                                });
                            }    
                        }    
                        // calculate milliseconds
                        ms = td%1000;
                        if (ms < 1) {
                            ms = 0;
                        } else {    
                            // calculate seconds
                            s = (td-ms)/1000;
                            if (s < 1) {
                                s = 0;
                            } else {
                                // calculate minutes   
                                var m = (s-(s%60))/60;
                                if (m < 1) {
                                    m = 0;
                                } else {
                                    // calculate hours
                                    var h = (m-(m%60))/60;
                                    if (h < 1) {
                                        h = 0;
                                    }                             
                                }    
                            }
                        }

                        // substract elapsed minutes & hours
                        ms = Math.round(ms/100);
                        s  = s-(m*60);
                        m  = m-(h*60);                                
                        // update display

                        //alert("I am testing"+row);
                        $('#' + $.APP.dir + '_ms').html($.APP.formatTimer(ms));
                        $('#' + $.APP.dir + '_s').html($.APP.formatTimer(s));
                        $('#' + $.APP.dir + '_m').html($.APP.formatTimer(m));
                        $('#' + $.APP.dir + '_h').html($.APP.formatTimer(h));
                        // loop
                        $.APP.t = setTimeout($.APP.loopTimer,1);

                    } else {
                        // kill loop
                        clearTimeout($.APP.t);
                        return true;
                    }  

                }

            }    

        });

        $('#sw_start').live('click', function() {
        $.APP.startTimer('sw');
        });
```

My html code for is given below :

```
 <li  id='sw_start'>
    <div>
        <span id="sw_h">00</span>:
        <span id="sw_m">00</span>:
        <span id="sw_s">00</span>:
        <span id="sw_ms">00</span>
    </div>
 </li>

 <li  id='sw_start'>
    <div>
        <span id="sw_h">00</span>:
        <span id="sw_m">00</span>:
        <span id="sw_s">00</span>:
        <span id="sw_ms">00</span>
    </div>
 </li>
```

Comment: If the browser is refreshed or closed you can't continue the timer. Javascript runs only in the current window. In order to do it you would need some kind of backend process on the server, likely accessed through an AJAX call

Comment: Can you give me some idea?I am stuck on that problem @-Cfreak

Comment: Do you know any backend languages like PHP or Python? What kind of server are you running? Here's an AJAX tutorial: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started